# gradlew getting 403 on fetching gradle binary

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I'm kind of stuck troubleshooting an issue.

- During a Jenkins build I see the following error:

  `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip`
- This also happens when I run `./gradlew clena build` in my project in `localhost` (no VPN, etc)
- It does NOT happen when I paste the binary URL into my browser (so that old gradle version does exist)

Binary referenced in `gradel-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If I try to access http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip, I get Couldflare 1020, which inficates a firewall rule has been violated. It seems like there is a server-side problem...

Comment: Oh, it works with HTTPS but not with HTTP. It seems that a firewall blocks port 80 but allows 443...

Comment: @dan1st good catch! That resolved the 403 locally :) I'll update `gradel-wrapper.properties` accordingly.
Appreciate it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments have pointed you to answer, but to clarify with more information and references.

Gradle announced on October 17, 2019, that starting on Janurary 2020, **all** Gradle services will no longer serve requests made with HTTP.

The URL you have specified for in `gradle-wrapper.properties` is for HTTP, switch to the HTTPS URL and it should work.

Reference: https://blog.gradle.org/decommissioning-http

Comment: Ok, thank you for clearing up the background on that Francisco!